# How to make the inside of the div div centered

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I have a question about div within a div div centered on the screen, according to the inside of the div is adaptive
 Best can be a row of three equal div two shows that no matter how big is the screen

```css
.wrap {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrap>.child {
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-width: 32%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer, and easier to understand.. It's not clear what's wrong, and what you're asking.

Comment: That description is pretty brutal.  I can't make it out.  Is the issue the small gap to the right of the third column?  That's to be expected.  You set the width to 32% which would make three of them only fill up 96% of the width.

Comment: You want them centered horizontal, vertical, both, ...?

Comment: Watch carefully you will find that the red div is not centered just next to the left, the right of the blank obviously a lot

Comment: I also want to 100/3 but in that case is 33.333...I don't know how to write

Comment: Still no clue, dude.  Maybe add `padding-left: 3%; box-sizing: border-box;` to `.wrap`?  Are you just trying to center the columns?

Comment: Thank you Joseph Marikle I think it should be ok, although with padding - left, I think is a kind of method is not by modifying the padding - left, is automatically calculate if a row is 4 when each div should be 25% (and I'm Chinese my English is not very good, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```css
.wrap {
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px:
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}
.wrap>.child {
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-width: 32%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may understand the wrong I mean, I am very sorry my English is limited)

Comment: @Jasonzhao: ok... i read again... do you want the .wrap to keep the same size in the center of the screen?

Comment: Yes， I want his child centered to display an element But Joseph Marikle already help me to solve。Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create three equal width columns and not being able to use `33.3333%`, you've opted to instead just try to center them.  First of all, the biggest issue you have is not using `box-sizing:border-box`.  That rule will include the border width and padding in calculating a percentage width.  So you can make your code like so:

```css
.wrap {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrap>.child {
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-width: 33.333%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
</div>
```

It doesn't directly address the stated issue, but it may be what you're really going for.

Comment: Thank you very much to success is the reason why I can't believe this is only 33.333%, I have tried many times before, can you give me explain a remainder cases, how to divide

Comment: @Jasonzhao If I understand you correctly, you want to know how this works.  Let's say we have 4 columns at 25% width.  If you set it to `width:25%` but also add a border (`border: 1px solid red` for example), it will make the width be `25%` + `2px` (left and right border).  That's why `33.333%` didn't work before.  Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` forces it to always be `25%` even with the border.  Basically, the border was your problem.  `box-sizing: border-box;` allows you to have a border and set the width to a percentage.

Comment: I feel you are a big cow, in China is very bad, to the the question plagued me for an afternoon, you know I tried to use 33%, but he will turn hours in screen layout changes。Thank you very much of my ass

Comment: Sorry, a lot of cows in China means that your technology is very much, I don't know if you can understand.My English is very bad

Comment: @Jasonzhao I didn't understand the cultural reference, but I took it as a compliment. No worries.

Comment: May be a description of the problem, I have a chance you come to China, I can introduce you to Chinese culture